# excel pop up window?

Tags: vba, excel, popup

Hay guys..
I'm building a new table using Excel. I want to use VB (maybe) to create a code that once a box (at the excel sheet) is "0" nothing happens but as soon as the box turn to "1" a window popup. in the window I wish to write "You now have more than 50 points".

Is it possible? If I can't use VB, How can I do it?
I'll be happy for some help with the code as well, I don't know VB so well...

Thanks!!
Amihay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Worksheet_Change Event](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm).  You can then use something like Msgbox("You now have more than 50 points.") to display an alert if the criteria is met.